# API.AI: possible multiple intents in a result

Tags: dialogflow-es, azure-language-understanding, api-ai

API.AI returns a top scoring intent. I was wondering could we have lower scoring intents in the same response like LUIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent an email and API.ai staff confirmed only top scoring intent is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misread the question initially and thought this was a LUIS question.

For API.ai, it would appear that it does not return multiple intents in the **[response to a query](https://api.ai/docs/reference/agent/query#response)**.

---

*Original Answer:*

Yes, LUIS returns the following properties:

`"query", "topScoringIntent", "intents", "entities", "compositeEntities"`

The last three properties are arrays, and `"intents"` has all of the intents recognized by LUIS.

Comment: Do you know API.AI returns multiple intents like LUIS?

Comment: I updated my answer, but the answer looks like a no. Sorry I misread your question!

Comment: @StevenG can you help with this `api.ai` question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46107516/6144372 Please?

Comment: @HammadNasir, sorry but I'm more of a LUIS person; you should perhaps contact [Leon Nicholls](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594751/leon-nicholls), he seems more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: @StevenG. how can I contact him?

Comment: You could try doing an Stack Overflow mention to get his attention.