# API.AI: How to stop AsyncTask on click of the AIButton?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, onclicklistener, api-ai

I’m using `AIButton` in my app and I have a `AsyncTask` which gets executed after AIButton is clicked and receives some command and AsyncTask sometimes takes too long to execute.

Here’s my code:

```
final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration("xxx",
                AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
                AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);

listenButton = (AIButton) findViewById(R.id.micButton);

config.setRecognizerStartSound(getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.test_start));
config.setRecognizerStopSound(getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.test_stop));
config.setRecognizerCancelSound(getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.test_cancel));

listenButton.initialize(config);
listenButton.setResultsListener(this);
```

Here's the `AsnycTask`:

```
class translate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String translatedText = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loading.setMessage("Loading");
        loading.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String text = params[0];
        String toBeConvertedIn = params[1];

        Log.d("TEXT", text);
        Log.d("TBCI", toBeConvertedIn);

        try {
            String encodedText = URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");
            HttpHandler httpHandler = new HttpHandler();
            String url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=xxxxxxx&text=" + encodedText + "&lang=" + toBeConvertedIn;
            String jsonStr = httpHandler.makeServiceCall(url);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    Log.d("jsonObj", String.valueOf(jsonObj));

                    JSONArray translatedTextObj = jsonObj.getJSONArray("text");

                    for (int i=0; i<translatedTextObj.length(); i++) {
                        translatedText = translatedTextObj.getString(i);
                        Log.d("translatedText", translatedText);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        return translatedText;
    }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            hTV.setText(s);
            if (loading.isShowing()) {
                loading.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm calling above given `AsyncTask` in `onResult()` method like this:

```
public void onResult(final AIResponse response) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResult");

            Log.i(TAG, "Received success response");

            // this is example how to get different parts of result object
            final Status status = response.getStatus();
            Log.i(TAG, "Status code: " + status.getCode());
            Log.i(TAG, "Status type: " + status.getErrorType());

            final Result result = response.getResult();
            Log.i(TAG, "Resolved query: " + result.getResolvedQuery());

            Log.i(TAG, "Action: " + result.getAction());
            final String speech = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();

            final Metadata metadata = result.getMetadata();
            if (metadata != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Intent id: " + metadata.getIntentId());
                Log.i(TAG, "Intent name: " + metadata.getIntentName());
            }

            final HashMap<String, JsonElement> params = result.getParameters();
            if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Parameters: ");
                for (final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : params.entrySet()) {

                    switch (response.getResult().getMetadata().getIntentName()) {
                        case "Translate":
                            if (entry.getValue() != null) {
                                if (entry.getKey().equals("translate")) {

                                    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                    LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                                    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.translate_alertdialog, null);
                                    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

                                    final EditText textToTranslate = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.text_to_translate);
                                    final AutoCompleteTextView chooseLanguage = (AutoCompleteTextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.choose_language);
                                    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages);
                                    chooseLanguage.setAdapter(adapter);

                                    dialogBuilder.setTitle("What should I translate?");
                                    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Translate", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                            if (!textToTranslate.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                                                if (!chooseLanguage.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                                                    switch (chooseLanguage.getText().toString().toLowerCase()) {
                                                        case "french":
                                                            new translate().execute(textToTranslate.getText().toString(), "az");
                                                            break;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                            //pass

                                        }
                                    });
                                    AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
                                    b.show();
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("null", "No translate parameter");
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.d("null", "No translate entry value");
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });

}
```

So, what I want is to stop all running AsyncTask when the AIButton is clicked so that previous tasks are stopped in order to execute new task. How to do this?

The problem here is that you can't do something like: `listenButton.onClickListener()` here.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I'm not instantiating it anywhere but calling it like `new translate().execute(param1, param2);` wherever I need it.

Comment: Add a new constructor to the `translate` class passing an object, i.e. Boolean and keep the instance of that object when you click the button. You check the value of the `Boolean` object in the `doInBackground` to see if the value change to `false` in order to exit. When you click the button you change the value of the `Boolean` object to `false`.

Comment: @EasyJoin.net the problem is there is no way to track onclick of the button in this case. Read the question again.

Comment: @HammadNasir you create instances of the `translate` class in other places other than the `onResult` method, and in particular in `case "french":`?

Comment: @EasyJoin.net but you have written "When you click the button you change the value of the Boolean object to false." How am I supposed to change the value here if there is no onclick?

Comment: @HammadNasir you have already define the `onClick` method where you create the `translate` instance. Am i missing some part of your code?

Comment: @EasyJoin.net `onClick` must be set on `listenButton`, right? All the code relevant to listenButton is written in the question.

Comment: please put some effort in making your code less nested. Not only is it extremely hard to read, it is impossible to test

Answer (score 2):

Use [boolean cancel (boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)).

Make the asyncTask a class variable.

```
AsyncTask translate_ = new translate();
```

Then call it like so in place.

```
translate_.execute(textToTranslate.getText().toString(), "az");
```

Within the button onclick cancel the asyncTask.

```
translate_.cancel(true);
```

Then check within your loop that the task has been cancelled and set a break.

```
for (int i=0; i<translatedTextObj.length(); i++) {
    translatedText = translatedTextObj.getString(i);
    Log.d("translatedText", translatedText);
    if(isCancelled())
        break;
}
```

These questions also give some more variety in how to choose to do this:

[Android - Cancel AsyncTask Forcefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully)

[How to stop asynctask thread in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821284/how-to-stop-asynctask-thread-in-android)

It would be wise to manage the task on  backpress  also. Perhaps cancel the task in the activity onpause.

```
public void listenButtonOnClick(final View view) {
    // aiService.startListening();
    // add more details in here

    if (aiService != null) {
        switch (currentState) {
            case normal:
                aiService.startListening();
                break;
            case busy:
                aiService.cancel();
                translate_.cancel(true);
                break;
            default:
                aiService.stopListening();
                translate_.cancel(true);
                break;
}
```

Or cancel the task when the `aiservice` is cancelled or stopped.

```
@Override
public void onListeningStarted() {}

@Override
public void onListeningCanceled() {
    translate_.cancel(true);
}

@Override
public void onListeningFinished() {
    translate_.cancel(true);
}
```

There's other ways it can be managed, explore your options.  Have a good look [at this](https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-android-client) and the SO questions linked above.

If you have a look at [the docs](https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-android-client).

[apiai-android-client/ailib/src/main/java/ai/api/ui/AIButton.java](https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-android-client/blob/master/ailib/src/main/java/ai/api/ui/AIButton.java)

```
@Override
protected void onClick(final View v) {
    super.onClick(v);

    if (aiService != null) {
        switch (currentState) {
            case normal:
                aiService.startListening();
                break;
            case busy:
                aiService.cancel();
                break;
            default:
                aiService.stopListening();
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

It's clear from [our discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154123/discussion-between-yvette-colomb-and-hammad-nasir) you're struggling with how to implement this.

Please study this [apiai-android-client/ Android SDK for api.ai/ Tutorial](https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-android-client#tutorial)

Go back to the basics. Forget about the `ai.api` for a while and learn the basics. [Browse](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=override%20click%20event%20android&oq=override%20click%20event%20android&aqs=chrome..69i57.9798j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) around, read the docs [Input Events](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) read questions and apply the programming principles.
For example:
[Android button onclick override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575959/android-button-onclick-override)

Beyond this I cannot help you any further.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do one following thing when canceling AsyncTask.
on your button click method.

```
public void AIButtonClick(View view){
  asyncTask.cancel(false);
}
```

and check in doInBackground if it's canceled then return from it.

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {     
     if(asyncTask.isCanceled()) return;
   }
```

Also on in your onPause method you have cancel it was well.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
     if(asyncTask!=null){
      asyncTask.cancel(false);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set resultListener for your AIButton and implement onCancelled() method canceling your AsyncTasks from there.

To mark an AsyncTask as required to stop you should call

```
asyncTask.cancel(false);
```

And in your AsyncTask you have to check periodically whether it was cancelled or not by calling `isCancelled()`. If this method returns true you should stop execution.

Comment: how can I set the resultListener for AIButton?

Comment: @HammadNasir you're already setting it: `listenButton.setResultsListener(this);`.

Comment: Okay! So I just need to put `asyncTask.cancel(false);` in AIButton's `onCancelled` and then check if it was cancelled in AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to cancel the AsyncTask class
translate.cancel()

if you want to cancel the server request I recommend to use OKHTTP has a cancel request feature